# Serve images in next-gen formats, replace the images without changing the old links

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to increase a website rank in PageSpeed Insights.
it's recommending me to change my images to the next-gen images.
The problem with this that the old images are already indexed and has a good rank on the search engines, also most of the images links are stored in the database not static links.

Is there a way that I can still have the same link which in my case has even the ext. (.png,.jpg) while serving the next-gen images.

Using the this code can't really help in my case, because as mentioned the images link are being loaded from the database, and this requires a lot of work and manual steps

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/yourImage.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img/yourImage.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="img/yourImage.jpg" alt="Your image">
</picture>
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and C# as the development language for the website.

Thanks in advance any suggestion or solution is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588983/serve-images-in-next-gen-formats might help you - if, as is recommended, you still provide a fallback link in the old format then they won't disappear from searches. P.S. This has pretty much nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC or C#, it's really a HTML and images issue.

Comment: i'm trying to get another approach as this requires a manual update, we have thousands of images we can bulk generate a WebP images but i looking for a solution that can solve the issue without the manual updates, as you know some images links are coming from the database

Comment: i'll try to edit my question and add more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nobody has answered I can give you the "how" but only from an `.htaccess` perspective.

Hopefully that is enough to allow you to apply the same rules in IIS.

### .htaccess way of doing it

```
AddType image/webp .webp

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp -f
  RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)\.(jpe?g|png)$ /$1.$2.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=EXISTING:1,E=ADDVARY:1,L]

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "(?i)\.(jpe?g|png)$">
      Header append "Vary" "Accept"
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

### Steps performed

1. What we do is check the headers the browser sends with `%{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp`

I think that can be written as
`<add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT}" pattern="image/webp" ignorecase="false">` in IIS (sorry that is the extent of my IIS knowledge without a live server to play on!)

2. Then we check that the request exists (the original file exists) on the next line (this is because technically it should 404 if the original image was a `jpg` and the request was for a `jpg`, you may decide to handle this differently).
3. Then we check that we have the same file but with `.webp` extension on the end (our converted image)
4. If the file exists with a `.webp` (step 3) extension and the browser accepts `image/webp` (step 1) we rewrite the request and add `.webp` to the end of the file name that the system will use to locate the file, we then return the type `image/webp` so that a browser knows what to do with it.
5. Finally in the last section we send back the header vary accept so the browser knows it is ok to use the image with a different mime type than expected.

In order to use the above method it relies on you placing the files in the same directory and naming them the same but with `.webp` on the end.

E.g.

`https://example.com/img/imagefolder/myimage.jpg`

would need a webp file named:

`https://example.com/img/imagefolder/myimage.jpg.webp`

to work.

Obviously as these are rewrites on the server side this should hopefully preserve your link juice (but bear in mind you are still sending a different file type so it may not work), but at least your end users will be happy.